# Trazer última data do Produto SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou realizando a seguinte consulta para trazer os produtos com a última data de venda deles:

```
  SELECT 

  P.ID AS 'Código', 
  p.Nome, 
  CONVERT(decimal(18,2),pe.Valor_Custo) as 'Custo', 
  CONVERT(decimal(18,2),pe.Porcentagem) as 'Mark-up', 
  CONVERT(decimal(18,2),pe.Valor_Venda) as 'Venda',
  e.Quantidade as 'Estoque',

  (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 DATA FROM Venda 
  left join Venda_Item_Produto vip on vip.ID_Produto = p.ID
  WHERE VENDA.Data BETWEEN '2018/01/16' AND '2019/01/16' AND vip.ID_Produto = p.ID

  ORDER BY Data DESC) AS 'Data Última Venda'

  FROM Produto P
  left join Produto_Empresa pe on pe.ID_Produto = p.ID
  left join Estoque e on e.ID_Produto = p.ID
```

Porém, no campo DATA Última Venda, ele me traz a mesma data em todos os registros. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Para além do `DISTINCT` estar a mais e o `LEFT JOIN` poder passar para `INNER JOIN` e remover o `vip.ID_Produto = p.ID` da cláusula `WHERE`, não parece estar nada errado. A não ser que realmente todos tenham a mesma data de última venda.

Comment: Se você quer que volte uma data de última venda válida, você tem que trocar o `left join Venda_Item_Produto` para `inner join Venda_Item_Produto`.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na subquery que você fez, ele está trazendo apenas uma data da tabela `Venda_Item_Produto`, note que se você executar apenas esse *Select*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 DATA 
  FROM Venda 
  LEFT JOIN Venda_Item_Produto vip 
    ON vip.ID_Produto = p.ID
 WHERE VENDA.Data BETWEEN '2018/01/16' 
   AND '2019/01/16' 
   AND vip.ID_Produto = p.ID
```

Ele vai trazer apenas uma data!

A solução é simples, basta usar a função `MAX` sobre a data, que ele vai trazer a última data de cada venda!